# Derived Algebra is nilpotent implies the lie algebra is solvable

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

How does one show that Derived Algebra is nilpotent implies the lie algebra is solvable.

My attempt: Let $L$ be such a Lie-algebra then $[L,L]$ is nilpotent so it is solvable. So $[L,L]^{(n)}=0$ for some $n$. What can I do after this?

Comment: $[L, L] = L^{(2)}$.

Comment: Hint: Both $[L,L]$ and $L/[L,L]$ are solvable, so...?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That seems mainly focused on the (much harder) converse of this problem.